# Set Cookie and display date plus 10 days

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Can you please let me how i can set cookie and display current date plus 10 days in jQuery.

For e.g:-

December 9 - 19, 2014

So once the user visits a webpage a cookie is set and the date is updated to current date plus 10 days.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: 
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
$.cookie('mycookie','1234',{ expires: 10, path: '/' });
```

Comment: Yes thanks. How i can display date plus 10 days in html as well once the cookie is set.

Comment: var currentTime = new Date();
currentTime.setDate(currentTime.getDate()+10);

Comment: How do i check if the cookie is set and set the date:-

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.cookie('mycookie','1234',{ expires: 10, path: '/' });
  var currentTime = new Date(); 
  currentTime.setDate(currentTime.getDate()+10);
  $("#date").html(currentTime);
});
</script>

Comment: Is this code alright:-

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.cookie('mydatecookie','1234',{ expires: 10, path: '/' });
  
  var currentTime = new Date();
  currentTime.setDate(currentTime.getDate()+10);
   
  if($.cookie('mydatecookie')){
   $("#date").html(currentTime);
  }
});
</script>

Comment: Also how can i display date format in:-
December 9 - 19, 2014

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Also, will this be cookie automatically deleted after 10 days?

Comment: You can make your own tostring()
Try http://jsfiddle.net/6es4x5ey/ 

Will be deleted

Comment: Also, Clark is there a way to store the date in the cookie. Currently the date changes every time the page refreshes.